# Asyncronous ICommand implementation with optional canExecute

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have following ICommand implementation, which works great, but I want to expand it so I can pass external canExecute parameter

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<object, Task> callback;
        private readonly Action<Exception> onException;
        private bool isExecuting;

        public bool IsExecuting
        {
            get => isExecuting;
            set
            {
                isExecuting = value;
                CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> callback, Action<Exception> onException = null)
        {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.onException = onException;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => !IsExecuting;

        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            IsExecuting = true;
            try
            {
                await callback(parameter);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                onException?.Invoke(e);
            }

            IsExecuting = false;
        }
    }
```

Can this implementation be extended in a way so when caller's CanExecute() changes, both Execute1AsyncCommand and Execute2AsyncCommand will acknowledge that? Here is my caller class:

```
public class Caller : ObservableObject
{
public ObservableTask Execute1Task { get; } = new ObservableTask();
public ObservableTask Execute2Task { get; } = new ObservableTask();

public ICommand Execute1AsyncCommand { get; }
public ICommand Execute2AsyncCommand { get; }

public Caller()
{
    Execute1AsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Execute1Async);
    Execute2AsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Execute2Async);
}

private bool CanExecute(object o)
{
    return Task1?.Running != true && Task2?.Running != true;
}

private async Task Execute1Async(object o)
{
    Task1.Running = true;
            
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>Thread.Sleep(2000)).ConfigureAwait(true);
        Task1.RanToCompletion = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Task1.Faulted = true;
    }
}
private async Task Execute2Async(object o)
{
    Task2.Running = true;

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000)).ConfigureAwait(true);
        Task2.RanToCompletion = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Task2.Faulted = true;
    }
}
}
```

In other callers I still want to be able to use `AsyncRelayCommand()` with just `callback` being mandatory. In this case `CanExecute` should be evaluated internally from `AsyncRelayCommand` as in my original implementation.

For completeness, here is my view:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Execute Task 1"
            Command="{Binding Execute1AsyncCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Execute Task 2"
            Command="{Binding Execute2AsyncCommand}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Task 1 running:" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task1.Running}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Task 2 running:" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task2.Running}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And ObservableTask class:

```
public class ObservableTask : ObservableObject
{
    private bool running;
    private bool ranToCompletion;
    private bool faulted;

    public Task Task { get; set; }

    public bool WaitingForActivation => !Running && !RanToCompletion && !Faulted;

    public bool Running
    {
        get => running;
        set
        {
            running = value;
            if (running)
            {
                RanToCompletion = false;
                Faulted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool RanToCompletion
    {
        get => ranToCompletion;
        set
        {
            ranToCompletion = value;
            if (ranToCompletion)
            {
                Running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Faulted
    {
        get => faulted;
        set
        {
            faulted = value;
            if (faulted)
            {
                Running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is after user press one button both become disabled until all tasks are done.

**Solution**

I ended up with the following implementation which so far works as intended:

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private bool isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<object, Task> execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;
    private readonly Action<Exception, object> onException;

    private Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null, Action<Exception, object> onException = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
        this.onException = onException;
        Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        else
            Dispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => !isExecuting && (canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter));

    private async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            try
            {
                isExecuting = true;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                await execute(parameter);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                onException?.Invoke(e, parameter);
            }
            finally
            {
                isExecuting = false;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _ = ExecuteAsync(parameter);
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Caller: ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableTask Task1 { get; } = new ObservableTask();
    public ObservableTask Task2 { get; } = new ObservableTask();
    public ObservableTask Task3 { get; } = new ObservableTask();

    public ICommand Execute1AsyncCommand { get; }
    public ICommand Execute2AsyncCommand { get; }
    public ICommand Execute3AsyncCommand { get; }

    public Caller()
    {
        // Command with callers CanExecute method and error handled by callers method.
        Execute1AsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Execute1Async, CanExecuteAsMethod, Execute1ErrorHandler);

        // Command with callers CanExecute parameter and error handled inside task therefore not needed.
        Execute2AsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Execute2Async, _=>CanExecuteAsParam);

        // Some other, independent command.
        // Minimum example - CanExecute is evaluated inside command, error handled inside task.
        Execute3AsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Execute3Async);
    }

    public bool CanExecuteAsParam => !(Task1.Running || Task2.Running);
    private bool CanExecuteAsMethod(object o)
    {
        return !(Task1.Running || Task2.Running);
    }

    private async Task Execute1Async(object o)
    {
        Task1.Running = true;
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); }).ConfigureAwait(true);
        Task1.RanToCompletion = true;
    }
    private void Execute1ErrorHandler(Exception e, object o)
    {
        Task1.Faulted = true;
    }

    private async Task Execute2Async(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            Task2.Running = true;
            await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); }).ConfigureAwait(true);
            Task2.RanToCompletion = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Task2.Faulted = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task Execute3Async(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            Task3.Running = true;
            await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); }).ConfigureAwait(true);
            Task3.RanToCompletion = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Task3.Faulted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you everybody for invaluable help!

Comment: How is the `AsyncRelayCommand` class supposed to know what happens in the caller? It's the responsibility of the caller to update the status of the command. You could for example set the `IsExecuting` property whenever `SomeCondition` or `OtherCondition` changes. Otherwise the command implementation must subscribe to changes to this properties.

Comment: @mm8 can this subscription be implemented within AsyncRelayCommand?

Comment: Why do you use `.ConfigureAwait(false);` when running a task? It actually means that the code below `await` may be executed on random ThreadPool thread rather on UI thread. I'm note sure but for me it seems that the race condition might occur

Comment: Good point, thank you. Changed to .ConfigureAwait(true)

Comment: I wouldn't write `ConfigureAwait` at all, because it captures sync context by default. So personally I think it's more confusing to have the call, even with `true`.

Comment: It's just a habit to keep code analyzers happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some ready-to-use solution.

- Regular synchronous delegate, thus it can replace simple `RelayCommand`.
- Delegate executed on a pooled Thread.
- `CanExecute` is `false` while command is executing, thus it will disable the control automatically.

**Implementation**

```csharp
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object param);
}

public class AsyncRelayCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    private Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        else
            Dispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter));

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                await Task.Run(() => _execute(parameter));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _ = ExecuteAsync(parameter);
}
```

**Usage**

```csharp
private IAsyncCommand _myAsyncCommand;

public IAsyncCommand MyAsyncCommand => _myAsyncCommand ?? (_myAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}));
```

*Note: you can't deal with `ObservableCollection` from non-UI Thread, as workaround I suggest this [one](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516).*

---

**Asynchronous delegate version**

```cs
public class AsyncRelayCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<object, Task> _executeAsync;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    private Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> executeAsync, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _executeAsync = executeAsync;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        else
            Dispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter));

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                await _executeAsync(parameter);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _ = ExecuteAsync(parameter);
}
```

**Usage**

```csharp
private IAsyncCommand _myAsyncCommand;

public IAsyncCommand MyAsyncCommand => _myAsyncCommand ?? (_myAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(async parameter =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks aepot, this almost works. There are two issues tho. When the task is done the UI is not being automatically refreshed. I have to click or nudge the window for buttons to re-enable themselves. Also if I opt-out with providing external CanExecute ```new AsyncRelayCommand2(p => Execute2Async(p))``` I can smash that button and initiate execution many times whilst task is already running.

Comment: @Pawel ah, i see the problem. Here you don't need to wrap the code with async stuff. Do job directly inside the command as you may `Thread.Sleep` without wrapper. As simple as it could be. Try change `Execute2Async` to `Thread.Sleep(2000)`. It will work as expected.

Comment: ok, there is some progress :) What I'd rather do is to replace ```Action<object> execute``` with ```Func<object, Task> execute``` and just ```await _execute(parameter);``` in ```ExecuteAsync```. I'm still testing this out but your solution looks promising

Comment: @Pawel are you really need an async delegate? Why? What kind of job will inside? Some I/O-bound stuff as network request? What exactly? If yes, you may use `Func<Task>` and execute if without `Task.Run()` but i'm not sure if it's really needed.

Comment: @Pawel added `async` delegate version. But I still think that it's a kind of redundancy. `new AsyncRelayCommand2(async p => await Execute2Async(p))`

Comment: @Pawel I think, there's a way to make some universal version that accepts both `Action<object>` and `Func<object, Task>`. It can really make the code simple because you don't need `async` delegate in every command but always need to keep the UI responsive. Maybe I can do that if you need.

Comment: Sure, in the actual code I'm not doing ```Task.Delay(2000);``` :) I'm asynchronously calling data access services. I thought I do need an async delegate for that, but now that you planted this idea of handling async stuff inside the command I am going re-think that. Especially context of handling errors.

Comment: @Pawel instead of doing `async` stuff in Command, you may implement Producer/Consumer programming pattern (google knows a lot about it). :) Just an option.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Caller` had a method called `CanExecute` like this:

```
 private bool CanExecute()
 {
     return SomeCondition && OtherCondition;
 }
```

Then you would be able to pass it to your `AsyncRelayCommand` as an instance of delegate type `Func<bool>`, of course, if your `AsyncRelayCommand` defined constructor with the needed parameter:

```
    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> callback, Func<bool> canExecute, Action<Exception> onException = null)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.onException = onException;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
```

Then you pass it to the constructor like this:

```
MyAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(ExecuteAsync, CanExecute, ErrorHandler);
```

Thus, your `AsyncRelayCommand` would be able to invoke `canExecute` delegate and will get the actual results.

Or you can leave `CanExecute` as the property, but when you create `AsyncRelayCommand`, wrap it to the lambda expression like this

```
MyAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(ExecuteAsync, () => CanExecute, ErrorHandler);
```

To apply fallback logic to your `CanExecute` for `AsyncRelayCommand` you can change the code in the following way:

- have an instance variable of type `Func<bool>` called, let's say, `_canExecute`. Then assign it in the constructor with whatever value accepted as the argument `Func<bool> canExecute` even if it's `null`. Then in your `public CanExecute(object param)` just check if `_canExecute` is `null`, just return `!IsExecuting` as you're doing it now, if it's not `null`, then return whatever `_canExecute` return.

Comment: Thanks E. Shcherbo. Caller's CanExecute can be a method I think. I want however AsyncRelayCommand ```canExecute``` to be optional so when ommited AsyncRelayCommand can internally evaluate its own CanExecute as it does currently. So if I chage signature like ```Func<bool> canExecute = null``` what should I do with this canExecute func if not null?

Comment: There are several ways I can see to resolve it. One of the way is the following: you're still going to have an instance variable of `Func<bool>` to save `canExecute` delegate object, then your `CanExecute` property can be implemented like this `public bool CanExecute => canExecute == null ? !IsExecuting : canExecute();`

Comment: You meant ```CanExecute()``` method, right? I think I already tried that with no success ```public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => canExecute == null ? !IsExecuting : canExecute();``` that's because caller's ```ExecuteAsync``` is setting ```SomeCondition = false;``` on entry and back to ```true``` on exit. Caller's CanLoad() is invoked after I click button, but before ```SomeCondition = false;``` so ```SomeCondition``` is always true

Comment: Thanks E. Shcherbo. I edited question and provided more details

Comment: This solution works almost perfectly. I can smash both buttons and tasks won't start if either task is already running, which is what I wanted. However what I also want is to buttons being disabled if either task is running. Currently, when task is running both buttons stays enabled, just inoperative.